# Magento CE v2.0.2 and MDVA-84 Patch

Tags: magento2, upgrade, patches

Last night, there was an update in **Magento CE v2.0** and also a release of patch **MDVA-84**. Any possible problems that may encounter by anyone of us? Magento also fixed issues which mostly includes the upgrade problems between previous versions of magento 2.

They are also not supporting the downloads of **Magento CE v2.0.0** and **Magento CE v2.0.1** and asking to download **Magento CE v2.0.2** directly which means that it might be good to go completely with magento 2 now?

Possible suggestions, problems, bugs reported here below may help us all. See the link below for more information:

[Release Notes Magento CE 2.0.2](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-2.0.2.html)

[Technical Bullets](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/tech_bull_201-upgrade.html)

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that the 2.0.2 doesn't have any serious changes with exception of the upgrade fix. So if you want to avoid resolving upgrade issue in the future, go straight to 2.0.2, but if you previously installed 2.0.0 and 2.0.1, tech bulletin describes how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

looks like there is nothing serious:

**Fixed Issues**:
- Magento no longer throws an exception or fatal error when upgrading from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1.
- You can now successfully upgrade from Magento 2.0.0 to Magento 2.0.1 using composer update.
- You can now upgrade from Magento 2.0.0 to Magento 2.0.1 using Packagist.
- If your server runs PHP 7, the updater application no longer throws an error during the Magento upgrade process. See the technical bulletin for more information.

However, if you installed Magento 2.0.1 from an archive, you will encounter problems later with future upgrades. For this reason, we highly recommend that you upgrade your installation to Magento Community Edition, version 2.0.2.